# Capybara-1.1.1 conflicts with capybara (~> 0.4.0)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, capybara

I updates my gems, now I get this error:

```
 Unable to activate capybara-mechanize-0.2.7, because capybara-1.1.1 conflicts with capybara (~> 0.4.0) (Gem::LoadError)
```

I've googled and searched SO, but I'm a bit of a n00b and not really sure what I need to do next.

Thanks for your time,

Mike

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to delete conflicting gem by invoking `gem uninstall capybara`. You will be the prompted which version to delete.

To remove all old gems in one swipe just use `gem cleanup`.

After cleaning old version which, hopefully, you don't need you should be ok. Otherwise, consider using bundler (http://gembundler.com/) to manage gems in your projects and RVM, where you can have completely separate gemsets.

Answer (score 1):

My general workflow is as follows:

1. In Rails/Sinatra etc applications I put vendor/cache in my .gitignore and run bundle pack which installs gems into that directory. That way I can keep installed gems local per application.
2. In my daily workflow I use RVM to switch ruby versions and install gems into gemsets which I can port across RVM rubies. http://beginrescuened.com. A popular and more lightweight alternative to RVM is https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.

So bundler manages my gem dependencies in a sane manner and RVM lets me manage gems at a granular level. I went through the dependency hell of plain old rubygems a while back, never again.

Answer (score 0):

You've either got two versions of Capybara installed (both 1.1.1 and some other version). You can go a `gem list --local` (or if you're using Bundler do a `bundle show`) and uninstall one of them.

Or possibly you've specified that you want versions `~> 0.4.0`, and the version number `1.1.1` is out of that range. That is, the specified version range `~> 0.4.0` will only work with `0.4.0 .. 0.4.x`, and not `0.5.x` or higher.